# The statements inside the label executes even if the condition fails.Can anyone explain what I'm doing here wrong?

Tags: perl, goto

```
my $a =10;
my $b =200;
my $c,$d;
goto UP if ($a > 20);
$d = $c + $b;
print "$d\n";
UP:
$c = $b -$a;
print "$c\n";
```

The above statements inside the label executes even if the condition fails.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. When I set `$a` to 30 (which is > 20), the 1st `print` does skip as expected. If I run the code as is, then both `print`s will print, also as expected.

Comment: Side note: I advise `use warnings;` and `use strict;`. For instance, you should have parentheses around the `my` list `my ($c, $d);`, and its best to set `$c` to something as well.

Comment: I tried as mentioned Costaparas.But I want the code to execute only if the condition passes.Even if the condition fails the label gets executed.May I know how is this?

Comment: Right now, the 1st `print` is skipped if the condition is true, but the 2nd `print` will always execute. So, what do you want - do you want the first `print` to always execute, and the 2nd to only execute if the condition is true? Could you [edit] the question with more details as to the desired behavior, input/output.

Comment: Yes Costaparas.I want the 2nd print to work only if the condition is true.(By using goto)

Comment: What's with the insistence on `goto`? You don't need it here and it doesn't do what you want.

Comment: This can be easily solved using structured programming - conditions, loops, functions. Avoid `goto` altogether. The non-`goto` answers below are a standard way of doing this -- you effectively want an `if` statement conditional, and a `goto` seems messy and unnecessary here. (Avoid *spaghetti code*, please).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are mixing up how the labels and `goto` work. In fact, `goto` should never be used for flow control. It's really confusing.

This is how your code runs at the moment:

[image]

As you can see, the last two statements (those are after your `UP` label) are always executed. Perl will check the condition, and if it is true, skip ahead. If the condition is false, it runs the two statements following immediately, and then runs the label and the rest.

Labels don't make subroutines in Perl. They just give a line a name. The line of code is still executed normally.

If you want to do one or the other instead, you need an if-else construct. That's done like this in Perl.

```perl
my $a = 10;
my $b = 200;
my ( $c, $d );
if ($a > 20) {
    $c = $b -$a;
    print "$c\n";
} else {
    $d = $c + $b;
    print "$d\n";
}
```

Since you seem to insist on `goto`, you can make that work, but you need to tell it to stop execution.

```perl
my $a =10;
my $b =200;
my $c,$d;
goto UP if ($a > 20);
$d = $c + $b;
print "$d\n";
exit;  # <------------- this stops execution and ends the program
UP:
$c = $b -$a;
print "$c\n";
```

Of course your code won't do much, because both `$c` and `$d` are `undef`.

You should really turn on `use strict` and `use warnings`, and fix the problems both of these *pragmata* will show you.

Also note that `$a` and `$b` are reserved variables to be used inside [`sort`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort).

Comment: Thank you Simbabque for this information.Is there any way to run the goto statement only if the condition passes?

Comment: @Nandhu that is exactly what is happening here. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is equivalent to the following:<sup>[1]</sup>

```perl
A: my $a = 10;
B: my $b = 200;
C: my ($c, $d);
D: goto G if $a > 20;
E: $d = $a + $b;
F: print "$d\n";
G: $c = $b - $a;
H: print "$c\n";
```

As this better demonstrates, code execution doesn't stop once a label is encountered.

To emulate an if-then-else structure, you'd use

```perl
my $a = 10;
my $b = 200;
$a > 20 and goto ELSE;

my $d = $a + $b;
print "$d\n";
goto END;

ELSE:
my $c = $b - $a;
print "$c\n";

END:
```

You probably know this, but the following is a lot clearer and provides better scoping:

```perl
my $a = 10;
my $b = 200;
if ($a <= 20) {
   my $d = $a + $b;
   print "$d\n";
} else {
   my $c = $b - $a;
   print "$c\n";
}
```

---

1. After a couple of off-topic fixes